# Multiple MySQL query in php. I'm trying to figure out how to use radio buttons to search for multiple queries in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Multiple MySQL query in php. I'm trying to figure out how to use radio buttons to search for multiple queries in a database.I am able to search for ID but I cant' search for company, firstname, lastname using the radio button.Here's what i got.

```
//search from search box
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchQ = $_POST['search'];
    $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchQ); //??
//Search by ID
// mysqli_query need 2 parameters $Db and query
    $queryID = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE id like '$searchQ'") or die ("could not search by ID");
    $countID = mysqli_num_rows($queryID);

    //Search by company
    $queryCompany = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE company like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by company ");
    $countCompany = mysqli_num_rows($queryCompany);

    //Search by first name
    $queryFname = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE first_name like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by First name ");
    $countFname = mysqli_num_rows($queryFname);

    //search by last name
    $queryLname = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE last_name like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by Last name ");
    $countLname = mysqli_num_rows($queryLname);

    //search all
   $queryAll = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers") or die ("could not search by All ");
    $countAll = mysqli_num_rows($queryAll);

    if ($countID == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no search!';
     }


    else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryID)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $com = $row['company'];
            $fname = $row['first_name'];
            $lname = $row['last_name'];

            $output ='<div> '.$id.' '.$com.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>';
        }
    }
}


?>

<h1>Customer List</h1><br /><br /><br />

<h3>Search from criteria</h3>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search database" /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="Id" />Id<br />
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="company" />Company<br />
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="firstName" />First Name<br />
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="lastName" />Last Name<br />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form><br /><br />

<p></p>

<?php  print($output);
```

Comment: You have no `SearchCategory` POST array.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how I'd do it, but trying to stay most close to your given code, a possible solution would look something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $_POST['search']);

    switch (strtolower($_POST['SearchCategory'])) {
        case 'id':
            $query = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE id like '$searchQ'") or die ("could not search by ID");
            break;
        case 'company':
            $query = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE company like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by company ");
            break;
        case 'firstname':
            $query = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE first_name like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by First name ");
            break;
        case 'lastname':
            $query = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers WHERE last_name like '%$searchQ%'") or die ("could not search by Last name ");
            break;
        case 'all':
        default:
            $query = mysqli_query($DB, "Select id, company,first_name, last_name from customers") or die ("could not search by All ");
    }

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no search!';
    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $com = $row['company'];
            $fname = $row['first_name'];
            $lname = $row['last_name'];

            $output ='<div> '.$id.' '.$com.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>

<h1>Customer List</h1><br><br><br>

<h3>Search from criteria</h3>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search database" /><br>
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="Id" /> Id<br>
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="company" /> Company<br>
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="firstName" /> First Name<br>
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="lastName" /> Last Name<br>
    <input type="radio" name="SearchCategory" value="all" /> All<br>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form><br><br>


<?php  print($output);
```

You could simplify this a bit in a few places, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But which of these will you recommend, mysqli or PDO?

Comment: At this point, I would probably recommend PDO, but that might be just because that's what I went to after `mysql*`, and when I did it supported named parameters and `mysqli` did not (I don't even know if it does now). PDO also supports lots of databases, which can be nice.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or nothing? Do you have error reporting enabled or have you checked the logs? Or is the query not working?